# How to change text box font color if font color is white(default by theme)?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I installed triggered scrollbox and it's working but text box where you have to write your e-mail has white background and white font(font for whole theme is white). SO i would like to change it to any other color.

Thing is that i can't acces CSS to change it so i have to do it somehow in HTML but i don't know how.

This is the code:

```
[gravityform id="9" title="true"  description="true"]
```

So question is how can I modify this gravity form code that change color of font?!

Vital information: other solutions can't help(CSS, etc.) bcs wordpress there is bought and it's pretty limited so i'm looking for a solution in HTML that can be implemented particulary in this line code.

Comment: Can you add `<style>`tags to the HTML (the header?) Gravityforms allows for adding classes to the forms created, but those classes still needs to get their styles from somewhere. If you have access to JS, you can do it there, but you will have to add some CSS somewhere, to manage.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by bought but if that means you don't have access to create a css file to override the current styles then maybe try this plugin https://wpmonks.com/blog/how-to-change-background-colour-of-gravity-form/

Answer (score 1):

You can set styles for input element in your HTML like this:

```html
<input style="color: pink !important; background-color: black !important">
```

May be you need (may be not) to add `!important` to your styles to overwrite existing ones.

Answer (score 1):

You can install plugin for custom css and add your custom css there to overide gravity form css.

Here is one simple plugin to do that: [Cssor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cssor/)

Answer (score 0):

Write the below css in your style.css

```
input{
     color: #000; // if it is not applying, use ! important
}
```

It works for all input boxes